# HTTPS url not valid

Tags: url, facebook-apps

I created an app to be used in a page tab. I have it hosted on my server which has a SSL protocol associated. However, the https url hasn't the usual naming (you can see it below):

https://secure395.websitewelcome.com/~rexdot/discoverylocker/

Is there any reason FB doesn't accept this? I'm sure this is the https url, it was given from my server support. And I'm also sure the app is there and fully working.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to post that URL directly on facebook.com results in: _“The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe: websitewelcome.com”_ – so you can either try to appeal that, or get another domain to run your app from.

Answer (score 0):

according to hostgator only solution is to pay for your own SSL. I've used other hosting services with reseller accounts and never had this issue before. In fact, the apps were running fine on those shared SSL certs from other companies.

So, one big reason why hostgator is not the way to go... their shared SSL is for websitewelcome.com which has been flagged as spam.